# Geometry Nodes: Seaweed type of blobs that float underwater and are affected by collisions

Tags: geometry-nodes

Can this be done with Geometry Nodes but better, I wonder (Avatar 2 inspired):

[image]

The blobs should wave independently but also react to collisions.

---

Here's one very close to what I wanted, yay :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpHK9ZIaDg0

Comment: ...yeah, but just collisions with the hand....so you could easy recreate it with softbodies and it would be performant because no collisions to other objects ;)

Comment: If you want to fake this effect, as shown in the video, why don't you just recreate it?

Comment: @quellenform Thanks for editing it in the answer, didn't realize. I found out about it way later, I think it might be of use for someone wanting to create this kind of effect with Geometry Nodes. Yes, I'm going to recreate it also :)

Comment: Oh, then it would actually be great if you share your experience here in conclusion, and write an answer to your question that explains a bit how the task could be solved. That would be a great addition to this platform and people looking for help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to a short question:

No, you can't do that with *Geometry Nodes*.

Unfortunately, there is no possibility with *Geometry Nodes* to calculate complex collisions or to let objects interact in this way.

For this task you need [Physics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/soft_body/index.html).

Comment: I think it is possible - but it wouldn't be performant and maybe the wrong tool to do it. But i think it would be possible - although i cannot prove it ;) (and of course i mean with simulation nodes)

Comment: @Chris It would actually be partially solvable (at least the wavelike motion), but it depends very much on the shape of the objects. And it would be an absolutely insane effort to produce even a somewhat acceptable result. With *Animation Nodes*: maybe. With *Physics*: Yes. But *Geometry Nodes*: No, because any workaround would only produce a miserable result and it wouldn't be a "real collision" in any case.

Comment: i agree about the effort: and it won't be worth the effort ;)